# MySQL writing to net

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, database, mysql5

I have a server that has been running at high CPU load due to MySQL activity, when i run the command `mysqladmin pr` i often see a few queries with the state "writing to net". I had a look around and couldn't find much out about this other than the fact i read somewhere that this shouldnt be expected in usual MySQL activity. Any ideas what this could mean?

Running MySQL 5.0.91-community on CentOS 4.8

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? Is from localhost using a tcp connection? The local socket? Connecting from a remote server?

Comment: standard PHP connection to mysql over localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Writing to net" means that MySQL is writing a packet to the network interface. You mentioned you have PHP connecting via localhost; do you have any remote network connections at all?

Comment: i do have connections to a few other servers within my network connecting via IP - would that explain it?

Comment: It could. Are the queries in the writing to net state queries that get sent to remote machines?

Comment: just seen one - doesnt appear to be for a remote connection as host is localhost and db/user are both local